# Как сделать плавное вращение объекта?

Tags: c++, qt

Никак не получается плавно вращать вот эту часть:

```
    {
            QPoint p0(600, 500);
            QTransform t;
            t.translate(p0.x(),p0.y());
            t.rotate(-45);
            t.translate(-p0.x(),-p0.y());
            carPainter.setTransform(t);
            update();

        //дверь
            carPainter.setBrush(QBrush(Qt::white));
            QPolygon polygon;
            polygon << QPoint(650,430) << QPoint(730,430) << QPoint(730,600) << QPoint(600,600) << QPoint(600,500);
         carPainter.drawPolygon(polygon);


        carPainter.setBrush(QBrush(Qt::white));
         carPainter.setBrush(QBrush(Qt::red));
        carPainter.drawRect(600,500,129,100);
        //ручка
        carPainter.setBrush(QBrush(Qt::black));
        carPainter.drawRect(700,520,20,10);



    }
```

Пытался сделать плавное вращение через QTimer, но совсем не получается.

Comment: а где QTimer то?

Comment: я его не стал сюда добавлять, так как ничего не получилось сделать с QTimer.